# Disable recent apps button as device owner

Tags: android, device-owner

This subject has been beat to death, but I'd like to give it one more shot.  Every query I do from this site or basically google give several hint/tips on handling when the button is pressed, but from what I understand the Samsung Knox has the ability to disable the button, and I'm wondering if that's a custom implementation baked into knox or just something i'm completely missing.

My application will be set as the device owner application for other reasons, but I do not see any low level items regarding the recent apps button.

I am currently targeting Android 21 (5.0). We currently use commercial (non root, multiple manufacturer and OS level) phones that we provide with one of our apps being mapped to the home button and monitors accessibility, and the primary application we attempt to keep in the foreground.

A few things...

- I'm not interested in making my application a kiosk application so that is not an option for mean at this time.
- I can monitor for the Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS and bring my application to the front (or handle differently), but this still allows for the button to be pressed and the screen to load for a bit.
- I've attempted all of the options for  getWindow().getDecorView() and setting the flags of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION, SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY, SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE (different combinations of the flags) during the OnResume, OnWindowFocusChanged, and as a callback listener on the 'setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener'.  This works OK for a while but after several pull down attempts on my Pixel 2 the navigation is stuck open.

I'm not very well versed in the capabilities of an application that is the device owner, but I cannot find this lower level configuration option available.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you want this?  I'd get it if you were a kiosk app and wanted to stop jailbreaking out of the app, but I see no other non-malicious usecase for this.  If you just want your app not to appear in recents there's ways to do that.

Comment: That said, StatusBarManager can do this.  But you need to be a system app as well as device owner.  And its unofficial functionality that can be changed or removed at any time.

Comment: The applications are not installed on normal people's phones.  They are sideloaded on company phones.

Our applications currently aren't system apps.  One of them we map to the home button and the primary one is the one we want the user 'stuck' in. The recent activities button is just an annoying button that confuses and interrupts users.  Currently if they press it the home application (an accessibility application that monitors of events taking place).

Comment: Yeah, my guess is you're getting it wrong there.  That sounds like the reasoning of a UX designer who doesn't like recents and doesn't realize how actually useful it is to the user's workflow.  But there definitely is no way to do that on a non-system app.  If you really want to be taking complete control over the device like this, you should be a kiosk app.  Using hacks like an accessibility app to do this is only going to cause huge long term maintenance issues.  And an eventual lawsuit when someone actually needs accessibility and can't use it.